# Ease in and out when using constant interpolation

Tags: animation, interpolation

I am making an animation which contains thousands of key frames as it is musical.

This requires constant interpolation so that the ‘hit’ stops and starts at exactly the right time.

However, constant interpolation is either on or off with nothing in between. This means that an animated object pretty much disappears from one position to the next.

So the question is this. How can I make constant interpolation ease in/out over (say) 3 frames instead of one? It is not practical to use Bézier curves and change every point; there are thousands of them.

Thank you.

Andy

Comment: Constant interpolation is what it is and it works how it works. I think you would be better off accepting the fact that you are going to need to use different interpolation. The better question would be how to do that practically with thousands of keyframes. Python scripting seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have no knowledge of python unfortunately. I guessed that might be the case but was hoping for another solution.

Comment: I am not that familiar with modifying animation curves in Python myself so I can't answer. But I think it might be useful for you to ask another question about doing what you want in Python specifically. Could be something like "How to convert constant interpolation to ease in/out interpolation over only a few frames with Python?". You probably need to make a duplicate of every point on the F-curve and move it to a few frames before the next point and change interpolation of all of them to something like Bezier. I think there are a lot of people here who would be able to help you with that.